# a distribution function

Tags: probability

If there are two multivariate independent gaussian variables, with their distribution function  $F_1$ and $F_2$ then by what conditions the function $F(x):=F_1(x)+F_2(x)-F_1(x)F_2(x)$ is a distribution function?

Comment: Remember the `$` around the LaTeX code.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the problem *without* the word *gaussian* included in it, and even more
to the point, *without* the word **multivariate** included in it. If $A$ and $B$
are (ordinary, single or univariate) independent 
random variables with distribution functions $F_1(\cdot)$ and $F_2(\cdot)$ respectively and $C$ is defined to be $\min\{A,B\}$, 
then

$$\begin{align}
F_C(x) &= P\{C \leq x\}\\
&= P\left(\{A \leq x\} \cup \{B \leq x\}\right)\\
&= P\{A \leq x\} + P\{B \leq x\} - P\left(\{A\leq x\}\cap \{B\leq x\}\right)
& \text{standard formula}\\
&= P\{A \leq x\} + P\{B \leq x\} - P\{A\leq x\}P\{B\leq x\} &\text{by independence}\\
&= F_1(x) + F_2(x) - F_1(x)F_2(x).
\end{align}$$
So, for *univariate* independent random variables with distribution
functions $F_1(\cdot)$ and $F_2(\cdot)$, the distribution of
the minimum of the two random  variables has the desired form
$$F_{\min}(x) =F_1(x) + F_2(x) - F_1(x)F_2(x)$$
and gaussianity is not needed for the result to hold.

For *multivariate* random variables (also called random
vectors), you should give some
details as to what is meant by $F_1(x)$ and $F_2(x)$, and
what is meant by the $F_1(x)+ F_2(x)$ when the two random
vectors are of different lengths.

Comment: Thanks. The phenomena being modelized corresponds to the sampling from two multivariate gaussian distributions (with different mean vectors, but the same spherical variance matrix). So, given a point in this real n-dimensional space, what is the probability of this point belonging to the first distribution or the second one, taking into account that it may also belong to both of them. At what point would it be reasonable to consider the independency of the two gaussian variables?

Comment: A different problem. Thus, please ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

For any function to be a valid distribution function, it needs to hold 4 properties,namely

- distribution function F is (not necessarily strictly) monotone non-decreasing.
- F is right-continuous.
- $\lim\limits_{x \to-\infty}F = 0$
- $\lim\limits_{x \to\infty}F = 1$

Now we rewrite the given expression as $F(x):=1-(1-F_1(x))(1-F_2(x))$ and we can easily observe the 4 properties in $F(x)$ given that $F_1(x)$ and $F_2(x)$ are valid distribution function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. The phenomena being modelized corresponds to the sampling from two multivariate gaussian distributions (with different mean vectors, but the same spherical variance matrix). So, given a point in this real n-dimensional space, what is the probability of this point belonging to the first distribution or the second one, taking into account that it may also belong to both of them. At what point would it be reasonable to consider the independency of the two gaussian variables?

Comment: Some peoiple are really upvoting automatically... Not an answer to the question.

Comment: upvoting? what for? I'm only interested in some answers to my questions. That's just another question related to the previous one that i did. I'm a recent newcomer in this forum and still don't know how to manage this well. Would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: As I said: `A different problem. Thus, please ask it as a new question.`

Comment: OK. However, it does have to do with my previous question